# Why javax constraint annotations don't work with Micronaut when input parameters are declared in the interface?

Tags: java, controller, annotations, constraints, micronaut

For example, I have a simple controller in Micronaut

```
@Controller("/hello")
public class MyApi implements Api {

  @Override
  public String hello(Integer i) {
    return "Num: " + i;
  }
}

@Validated
interface Api {

  @Get("/")
  String hello(@QueryValue @Max(10) Integer i);
}
```

Annotation `@Max` doesn't work, any numbers aren't validated. But the same example written in Spring works fine.

Comment: well but micronaut is not spring ;-) ... so what is the problem of having everything that belongs to the controller within the controller and the declaration of your api within the interface?

Answer (score 1):

Everything works when add dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micronaut.beanvalidation</groupId>
  <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```